# svn support in eclipse rcp application

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse, subversive, svnkit

I need to add svn support to my own eclipse rcp application. I need to show commit history and checkout specific version of a file from svn server.

Do I need to use sublipse or subversive or svnkit is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse and Subversion do the same thing. Subclipse is from SVN and Subversive is from the Eclipse camp. SVNKit is just the connector. I use Subclipse from the SVN camp primarily because it is built by the SVN community and usually always works flawlessly. Subversive is a less reliable plugin on the SVN side IMHO..

Subclipse also supports pretty much all the SVN detail level attributes and works right out of a SVN Perspective so you can manage everything from the IDE and Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVNKit if you are just looking for an API and you want to do all the work yourself to call the API and build a UI for the SVN features you want.  If you want to reuse the UI and work that was done already, then you would need to use Subclipse and drive its views and commands from your code.

Comment: Are there some examples/tutorials for subclipse?

Comment: I assume you mean for programmatically including it in an app?  It is not a common request, so no.  I would assume you could bundle the plugins with your app and should be able to invoke views or actions using the standard Eclipse plugin API for doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: I have a CNF viewer with custom project node type. I need to know how can I supply information necessary for subclipse views.

Comment: Subclipse mailing list is here:  http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=1043